# Pandas infrastructure data statistics plot with date per user

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to display some infrastructure usage daily statistics with Pandas but I'm a beginner and can't figure it out after many hours of research.

Here's my data types per column:

> Name                      object UserService               object
>   ItemSize                   int64 ItemsCount                 int64
>   ExtractionDate    datetime64[ns]

Each day I have a new extraction for each users, so I probably need to use the group_by before plotting.

Data sample:

```
          Name UserService  ItemSize  ItemsCount ExtractionDate
1   xyzf_s        xyfz        40           1     2018-12-12
2    xyzf1        xyzf        53           5     2018-12-12
3    xyzf2        xyzf        71           4     2018-12-12
4    xyzf3        xyzf        91           3     2018-12-12
14   vo12         vo          41           5     2018-12-12
```

One of the graph I am trying to display is as follow:

x axis should be the extraction date
y axis should be the items count (it's divided by 1000 so it's by thousands of items from 1 to 100)
Each line on the graph should represent a user evolution (to look at data spikes), I guess I would have to display the top 10 or 50 because it would be difficult to have a graph of 1500 users.

I'm also interested by any other way you would exploit those data to look for data increase and anomaly in data consumption.

Comment: I'm assuming Name shows who the user is. Are there duplicate line items for users? For example, could user vo12 have multiple lines with the same ExtractionDate?

Comment: Just seen this comment, no there is only one line per user and per date. It's daily data automatically retrieved from a Powershell script.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the user is shown in the name columns and there is only one line per user per day, to get the plot you are explicitly asking for, you can use the following code:

```
 # Limit to 10 users
 users_to_plot = df.Name.unique()[:10]
 for u in users_to_plot:
      mask = (df['Name'] == u)
      values = df[mask]
      plt.plot('ExtractionDate','ItemsCount',data=values.sort_values('ExtractionDate'))
```

It's important to look at the data and think about what information you are trying to extract and what that looks like. It's probably worth exploring with some individuals first and getting an idea of what is the thing you are trying to identify. Think about what makes that unique and if you can make it pop on a graph.

Comment: Woaw so fast thanks for your help realy appreciate.
I have the Following error with the code:

ValueError: Using arbitrary long args with data is not supported due to ambiguity of arguments.
Use multiple plotting calls instead.

Your assumption are right, one line per user per day.

Comment: Try now, I think I had a typo in there.

Comment: Just tried and it seems that you've corrected your typo. But the result is a bit weird, maybe because of my data.
Unfortunately I am unable to upload a picture from work at the moment.
Axe Y range from 0 to 140 that looks right but the date range from 1680 to 2000.
I'll make some test with your suggestions next Week, I won't be able to access my dev environment this weekend.

Comment: I was also assuming the data were sorted. Updated to account for that.

Comment: My data are stored in a CSV and I retrieve them in a DF like usually I guess. I don't understand your last comment? I cleaned the dataframe by replacing some value by dividing ItemCount by 1000 and convert it to an int, same for ItemSize but by 10, I also dropped some useless columns. The result is the sample I provided.
In the chart the date range was from 1680 to 2000 and in my DF I have daily data from the last 3 weeks in a datetime format.
And the line in the graph look like a single line starting at 1680 going up linearly with a 90° spike at 2000, I don't understand this as well.

Comment: Could you post some sample data? I'm not sure why it would look like that.

Comment: I won't be able to access my local linux VM at work during this week-end.
But you already have a sample in my original post, it's like this with 3000 users and 20 different days that makes ~60k rows and I filtered the ItemsCount for everything under 1000 items so it's probably a lot less in the dataframe.

Comment: Make sure that the ExtrationDate is a datetime data type and the edited code should fix it.

Comment: You are right it is not a datetime even if I use the Following method:
    df['ExtractionDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ExtractionDate'])
I also tried with format='%Y.%m.%d' but same problem.

Comment: Sorry ignore my previous comment:
It is a datetime64[ns] when I display dtype for the ExtractionDate collumn and I still have the weird date 1680 to 2000.